# Wordpress template - How to add class to li tag if submenu exist

Tags: menus, templates, add-submenu-page

for example i want create this menu:

```
<div class="menu_wrap">
 <ul class="nav sf-menu">
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Main Menu 3 without sub menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

how to add class="sub-menu" in li tag(s) that if sub menu is exist:

```
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 1</a>
```

if not exist echo li without class="sub-menu" :

```
<li><a href="">Main Menu 3 without sub menu</a></li>
```

i have this code for functions.php :

```
//Adds Menus
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'mainmenu' => 'The Main Menu'
            )
        );
    function dtuts_main_nav() {
        // display the wp3 menu if available
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'  => 'mainmenu',
            'menu'            => 'mainmenu',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'menu_wrap',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav sf-menu',
            'echo'            => true,
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 1,
            'walker'          => new themeslug_walker_nav_menu
        ));
    }
```

i can't write themeslug_walker_nav_menu class please help.

Comment: You can use jQuery (javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code I'm using, it's a custom nav walker for BootStrap but you could easily adapt it to your own. By the way, you could copy & paste my nav walker and be sure to change this line:

```
$class_names .= ' dropdown';
```

to

```
$class_names .= ' sub-menu';
```

Hope this helps.

```
/**
 * Custom Bootstrap Nav Walker
 */

class macho_bootstrap_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

/**
 * @see Walker::start_lvl()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
 */
public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
{
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\">\n";
}

/**
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $item Menu item data object.
 * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
 * @param object $args
 */
public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
{
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

    /**
     * Dividers, Headers or Disabled
     * =============================
     * Determine whether the item is a Divider, Header, Disabled or regular
     * menu item. To prevent errors we use the strcasecmp() function to so a
     * comparison that is not case sensitive. The strcasecmp() function returns
     * a 0 if the strings are equal.
     */
    if (strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if (strcasecmp($item->title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if (strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr($item->title);
    } else if (strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled') == 0) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr($item->title) . '</a>';
    } else {

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));

        if ($args->has_children)
            $class_names .= ' dropdown';

        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes))
            $class_names .= ' active';

        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title'] = !empty($item->title) ? $item->title : '';
        $atts['target'] = !empty($item->target) ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel'] = !empty($item->xfn) ? $item->xfn : '';


        $atts['custom'] = !empty($item->custom) ? $item->custom : '';

        // If item has_children add atts to a.
        if ($args->has_children && $depth === 0) {
            $atts['href'] = '#';
            $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
            $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-toggle';
            $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
        } else {
            $atts['href'] = !empty($item->url) ? $item->url : '';
        }

        $atts = apply_filters('nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args);


        $attributes = '';
        foreach ($atts as $attr => $value) {


            if (!empty($value)) {
                $value = ('href' === $attr) ? esc_url($value) : esc_attr($value);
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;

        /*
         * Glyphicons
         * ===========
         * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or Header we check the see
         * if there is a value in the attr_title property. If the attr_title
         * property is NOT null we apply it as the class name for the glyphicon.
         */
        if (!empty($item->attr_title))
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"></span>&nbsp;';
        else
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';


        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ($args->has_children && 0 === $depth) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }
}

/**
 * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
 *
 * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
 * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
 * depth and no ignore elements under that depth.
 *
 * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
 *
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param object $element Data object
 * @param array $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
 * @param int $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
 * @param int $depth Depth of current element.
 * @param array $args
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
 */
public function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output)
{
    if (!$element)
        return;

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

    // Display this element.
    if (is_object($args[0]))
        $args[0]->has_children = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);

    parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
}

/**
 * Menu Fallback
 * =============
 * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
 * and a manu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
 * menu manager the function with display nothing to a non-logged in user,
 * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
 *
 * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
 *
 */
public static function fallback($args)
{
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {

        extract($args);

        $fb_output = null;

        if ($container) {
            $fb_output = '<' . $container;

            if ($container_id)
                $fb_output .= ' id="' . $container_id . '"';

            if ($container_class)
                $fb_output .= ' class="' . $container_class . '"';

            $fb_output .= '>';
        }

        $fb_output .= '<ul';

        if ($menu_id)
            $fb_output .= ' id="' . $menu_id . '"';

        if ($menu_class)
            $fb_output .= ' class="' . $menu_class . '"';

        $fb_output .= '>';
        $fb_output .= '<li><a href="' . admin_url('nav-menus.php') . '">Add a menu</a></li>';
        $fb_output .= '</ul>';

        if ($container)
            $fb_output .= '</' . $container . '>';

        echo $fb_output;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Here goes your upvote.

Comment: TanQ.It code is worked.but i want disable other classes.this code echo several other class for ul tag and li tag and.... i want echo only class="sub-menu" for li tag .How can I do it!

Comment: Modify the above code to suit your needs. This was a starting point.

Comment: thanks . be true and worked.
Only I have a problem.i want add prefix char like "-".if item is child echo "<span>-</span>" before submenu item for indent.how can i do it?